# Read SDL2 texture without duplication

Tags: opengl, sdl-2

I tried to create heightmap with an png or jpg file. And it works too 75% but I can't solve the last 25...

Here is a picture of the map as png

[image]

And this is the resulting heightmap/terrain

[image]

As you can see the symbols starts to repeat and I have no clue why.

The code:

```
auto image = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
int lineOffSet = i*(image->pitch/4);
uint32 pixel = static_cast<uint32*>(image->pixels)[lineOffSet + j];
uint8 r, g ,b;
SDL_GetRGB(pixel,image->format,&r, &g, &b);
```

What I tried:

The number of vertices is correct(256x256).

```
int lineOffSet = i*(image->pitch/4);
```

4 represents the bytes per pixel which should be in this case 3 but than I get a complete different terrain (The pitch is 768). The range from i and j goes from 0-255.

I hope someone has a hint to solve this thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you calculate the address of the desired pixel wrong. You assume that one pixel is 4 bytes in size. It's usually more reliable to directly calculate the address in bytes and then cast to `uint32`. Try this:

```
uint32 pixel = *static_cast<uint32*>(image->pixels +
                                     image->pitch * i +
                                     image->format->BytesPerPixel * j);
```